Different ubuntu: cross-compilation of kernel is recompiled every time entirely
I have the same repository to cross-compile a Linux kernel on ubuntu 20.04 and ubuntu 24.04. More precisely, I do:
make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- Image modules -j4
On both distro, I'm using amd64 gcc 9.5 and the same cross-compilation toolchain.
On Ubuntu 24.04, the compilation recompiles EVERYTHING each time even if no file has been changed. It's not happening on Ubuntu 20.04.
On ubuntu 24.04:
make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- Image modules -j4
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CC      scripts/mod/empty.o
  CC      scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.s
  MKELF   scripts/mod/elfconfig.h
  HOSTCC  scripts/mod/modpost.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/mod/sumversion.o
  GEN     scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.h
  HOSTCC  scripts/mod/file2alias.o

  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  CHK     include/generated/timeconst.h
  CC      kernel/bounds.s
  CHK     include/generated/bounds.h
  CC      arch/arm64/kernel/asm-offsets.s
  CHK     include/generated/asm-offsets.h
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  HOSTLD  scripts/mod/modpost
  CC      init/main.o
  ....

File stamps have not been changed and everything else is the same. In other words, the only difference is Ubuntu 24.04 vs. Ubuntu 20.04.
How is that possible that everything gets recompiled on 24.04 and not on 20.04 (which is the expected behavior)?
##########################################################
EDIT 1
I have compared the outputs of both Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 24.04 with options -j1 and V=1 as suggested in the comments. On Ubuntu 24.04, very early, I have one additional compilation line:
set -e; : '  CHK     include/config/kernel.release'; mkdir -p include/config/;  echo "4.4.71$(/bin/bash ./scripts/setlocalversion .)" < include/config/auto.conf > include/config/kernel.release.tmp; if [ -r include/config/kernel.release ] && cmp -s include/config/kernel.release include/config/kernel.release.tmp; then rm -f include/config/kernel.release.tmp; else : '  UPD     include/config/kernel.release'; mv -f include/config/kernel.release.tmp include/config/kernel.release; fi
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.asm-generic \
            src=asm obj=arch/arm64/include/generated/asm
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.asm-generic \
            src=uapi/asm obj=arch/arm64/include/generated/uapi/asm
set -e; : '  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h'; mkdir -p include/generated/uapi/linux/;   (echo \#define LINUX_VERSION_CODE 263239; echo '#define KERNEL_VERSION(a,b,c) (((a) << 16) + ((b) << 8) + (c))';) < Makefile > include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h.tmp; if [ -r include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h ] && cmp -s include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h.tmp; then rm -f include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h.tmp; else : '  UPD     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h'; mv -f include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h.tmp include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h; fi
rm -f include/linux/version.h
set -e; : '  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h'; mkdir -p include/generated/;  if [ `echo -n "4.4.71-00005-g2fc62ed91813-dirty" | wc -c ` -gt 64 ]; then echo '"4.4.71-00005-g2fc62ed91813-dirty" exceeds 64 characters' >&2; exit 1; fi; (echo \#define UTS_RELEASE \"4.4.71-00005-g2fc62ed91813-dirty\";) < include/config/kernel.release > include/generated/utsrelease.h.tmp; if [ -r include/generated/utsrelease.h ] && cmp -s include/generated/utsrelease.h include/generated/utsrelease.h.tmp; then rm -f include/generated/utsrelease.h.tmp; else : '  UPD     include/generated/utsrelease.h'; mv -f include/generated/utsrelease.h.tmp include/generated/utsrelease.h; fi
mkdir -p .tmp_versions ; rm -f .tmp_versions/*
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=scripts/basic
(cat /dev/null; ) > scripts/basic/modules.order
rm -f .tmp_quiet_recordmcount
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=.
(cat /dev/null; ) > modules.order
mkdir -p kernel/

This compilation line only exists on Ubuntu 24.04:
  aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wp,-MD,kernel/.bounds.s.d -nostdinc -isystem /home/gregoire/tmp-inout/gcc-linaro-5.3.1-2016.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5.3.1/include -I./arch/arm64/include -Iarch/arm64/include/generated/uapi -Iarch/arm64/include/generated  -Iinclude -I./arch/arm64/include/uapi -Iarch/arm64/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -Iinclude/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -D__KERNEL__ -mlittle-endian -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -fno-PIE -mgeneral-regs-only -DCONFIG_AS_LSE=1 -mpc-relative-literal-loads -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Os --param=allow-store-data-races=0 -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fno-stack-protector -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -fno-var-tracking-assignments -g -pg -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=strict-prototypes -Werror=date-time -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO    -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(bounds)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(bounds)"  -fverbose-asm -S -o kernel/bounds.s kernel/bounds.c

Next line is identical on both environments:
set -e; : '  CHK     include/generated/bounds.h'; mkdir -p include/generated/; (set -e; echo "#ifndef __LINUX_BOUNDS_H__"; echo "#define __LINUX_BOUNDS_H__"; echo "/*"; echo " * DO NOT MODIFY."; echo " *"; echo " * This file was generated by Kbuild"; echo " */"; echo ""; sed -ne     "/^->/{s:->#\(.*\):/* \1 */:; s:^->\([^ ]*\) [\$#]*\([-0-9]*\) \(.*\):#define \1 \2 /* \3 */:; s:^->\([^ ]*\) [\$#]*\([^ ]*\) \(.*\):#define \1 \2 /* \3 */:; s:->::; p;}"; echo ""; echo "#endif" ) < kernel/bounds.s > include/generated/bounds.h.tmp; if [ -r include/generated/bounds.h ] && cmp -s include/generated/bounds.h include/generated/bounds.h.tmp; then rm -f include/generated/bounds.h.tmp; else : '  UPD     include/generated/bounds.h'; mv -f include/generated/bounds.h.tmp include/generated/bounds.h; fi

On Ubuntu 24.04, I have:
Ubuntu 24.04:
  File: kernel/bounds.c
  Size: 703         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 259,2   Inode: 14559530    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/gregoire)   Gid: ( 1000/gregoire)
Access: 2024-05-14 10:05:28.629197631 -0700
Modify: 2017-09-23 09:19:33.558726253 -0700
Change: 2024-05-07 15:44:11.170012538 -0700
 Birth: 2024-04-26 08:54:22.911042385 -0700
 
  File: kernel/bounds.s
  Size: 14617       Blocks: 32         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 259,2   Inode: 14559336    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/gregoire)   Gid: ( 1000/gregoire)
Access: 2024-05-14 10:26:03.478134345 -0700
Modify: 2024-05-14 10:26:03.467134218 -0700
Change: 2024-05-14 10:26:03.467134218 -0700
 Birth: 2024-05-04 21:27:59.503527455 -0700

As for the file systems:
Ubuntu 24.04:
/dev/nvme0n1p2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,stripe=32)
Ubuntu 20.04:
/dev/sda5 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)


Probably you are using a virtual environment? This might explain the clock (time zone) misalignment that make recognises as a signal for compiling the file.

That's a good suggestion but no, both installations are native (and time is correct).

Add V=1 to the make ... command and check what it does (in a bad case). You can add -d as well, but that will explode your logs. And try also to use -j1 to see step-by-step what's doing.

Regarding to the time topic, how is the filesystem mounted? Check all the flags and compare defaults. It's quite possible it simply doesn't update the time on the object files. You actually can run stat over the C-file and the respective o-file and confirm if it's like expected or not (make -j1 ... is helpful here as well).

Thank you @0andriy for helping. Good suggestions. I have edited the question with more info.

Btw. you put **EVERYTHING**, what does this exactly mean? Because if kernel version is changed, the make will recompile a few binaries along with the resulting vmlinux.o.

$PATH are identical. If I run twice the make command on 24.04, the second time, the system rebuilds everything which takes 5+ minutes. On my old 20.04, the second time takes 10 seconds.

Sorry, I'm lack of ideas, but at the same time I'm very curious of the root cause. That said, I can only wish you good luck and hopefully to see the answer soon by you (likely) or somebody else.

Thank you for helping. It's very challenging to debug the kernel makefile. I don't see any other similar questions with unexpected full recompilation (not a good sign for my situation). What puzzles me is that the only difference is 24.04 vs. 20.04.

I see at least the difference of the media (NVMe vs. some SSD or even spindel disk), which might also affect this. Dunno, as I said good luck!
